# Return array when using LET function

Tags: microsoft-excel

Currently, in Excel you can put the following in a cell:

```
={1,3}
```

and the formula will automatically spill to the side to show two cells: one with a one and the other with a three.
However, when using the LET function the following does not work:

```
=LET(x,1,y,3,{x,y})
```

Excel shows a dialog box asking to correct the formula. Am I doing something wrong? Please note that this was a minimal example.

What works is this:

```
=LET(x,1,y,3,{1,3})
```

But that is ridiculous.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Excel does not allow variables/ranges as input in arrays. You cannot do:

```
={A1,A5}
```

Or what you have:

```
=LET(x,1,y,3,{x,y})
```

You can do:

```
=LET(r,{1,3},r)
```

[image]

But that seems a little overkill, so if you want to use variables in the Let we need to use CHOOSE to do what we want.

```
=LET(x,1,y,3,CHOOSE({1,2},x,y))
```

[image]

But variables and range references cannot be part of an hard coded array.

---

Note there is a new function currently in Beta, HSTACK that can also do what you want:

```
=LET(x,1,y,3,HSTACK(x,y))
```

Comment: Cool! Exactly what I was looking for. Cheers!